# python os.path.isfile return with false

Tags: python

I am trying to search a file from different directories. i see that file does exist but still os.path.isfile returns false.

Since my file can be in multiple directory

```
import os

me = "/user"
my_home = "/home"
my_direcotry = "/user/jsbt"
my_file =  "/myfile"

my_path = me + my_home + my_directory + my_file

print(my_path)

if (os.path.isfile( my_path )) is True:
print ("Path was found")
else:
print ("Path does not exist")
sys.exit(0)
```

This above always results in false and it is not able to find the file.

But i do have myfile located

Any suggesion?

Comment: What happens if you replace isfile with exists? What if you do `cat /user/home/user/jsbt/myfile`

Comment: i also tried using with exists but same thing .. it results in false.

Comment: What about `cat /user/home/user/jsbt/myfile`? Does it actually find the file?

Comment: The code that you have shown above will result in multiple errors and not just from indentation.  Show us the code that you are actually using.

Comment: Sorry Guys typo .. My bad .. New to python and already loving it. :) fixed it.

Comment: @user3138102 If you have fixed the typo and that solved the problem, it would be good stackoverflow etiquette to delete the question.